# Numpy array , Find columns with 1s

Tags: python, numpy

I am looking to find columns in a numpy array where atleast one cell has a 1.

```
Input Array
[0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1]
[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0]
[0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0]
Expected Output
[0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`numpy.any`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) with `axis=0` (to flatten along the first axis, i.e. flatten along the rows):

```
>>> np.any(a, axis=0)
array([False,  True,  True,  True, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Of course, you can convert the boolean array into integers easily:

```
>>> np.any(a, axis=0)*1
array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply `|` (or) them all together:

```
>>> np.array([0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1]) | np.array([0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0])
array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1])
```